# How to get the entries of field generated by a loop

Tags: php

Please I need assistance on how to get the input values of field that was generated by a loop:

```
if($moreDetails){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($moreDetails)){
        $id="$row[id]";
        $sname="$row[sname]";
        $fname="$row[fname]";
        $sub="$row[$subject]";
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$id</td>
                <td>$sname</td>
                <td>$fname</td>
                <td><label for='score'></label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='score'/>
                    <input type='hidden' name='assessment'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}
```

[image: Form generated by a while loop]

My challenge is to get the input of the score entries.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the inputs array-style names.

```
if($moreDetails){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($moreDetails)){
        $id="$row[id]";
        $sname="$row[sname]";
        $fname="$row[fname]";
        $sub="$row[$subject]";
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$id</td>
                <td>$sname</td>
                <td>$fname</td>
                <td><label for='score'></label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='score[$id]'/>
                    <input type='hidden' name='assessment[$id]'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}
```

Then when you're processing the form, the `$_POST` parameters will be arrays, so you can access `$_POST['score'][$id]` and `$_POST['assessment'][$id]`.

It's also strange that you don't have `value="something"` in the hidden input. Are you using Javascript on the client side to fill this field in automatically?